# Perl - Regex substitution does not work

Tags: regex, perl

My regex is supposed to substitute a date in a larger csv file with the word 'TIMESTAMP'.

#### Example data

`TEXT12, TEXT312, 22.11.2013 13:30:16, abcd,`

#### Code

```
while(<>) {                                                           
  s/[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/TIMESTAMP/;
  print $_;                                                           
}
```

I checked the regex with RegexBuddy, it matches there successfully, but in the Perl program it doesn't work. Tried with Perl 5.14 and Perl 5.18 on Linux and Windows, no success.

Where is the mistake?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape dots `.`.

Try this one:

```
s/[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/TIMESTAMP/;
```

Comment: @royskatt in your case `.` and `\.` both match dot char.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is in your csv file, you might have several white spaces between numbers so use `\s+`

```
s/[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}\s+[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/TIMESTAMP/;
```

Also, when you want to match literal `.` char you have to escape it `\.` or use regex class for it `[.]`